# Lazy Route gets prefetched, ignoring webpack magic comments (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router, prefetch

I need to develop an application with server side authentication with a login view. If I want to use Vue Router to dynamically switch between login and index (the protected view), I need to avoid login view downloading (prefetching) index before succesful authentication, because if not, server will answer with the login page to the index prefetching request.

I'm trying to achieve this in the original Vue Router example that has two routes. Home and about. The first one is included and the second one is lazy loaded (but prefetched) which would be the protected page in the real application.

In order to avoid prefetching I have tried all the webpack magic comments I have found, but the prefetching is still hapenning.

Here is the code:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import VueRouter from "vue-router"
import Home from "../views/Home.vue"

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about"*/ /* webpackMode: "lazy" */ /* webpackPrefetch: false */ /* webpackPreload: false */ "../views/About.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

export default router;
```

And here the result:

[image: network result]

I don't want to disable the feature from the general webpack configuration because I want it for the rest of the application links. I want to disable it only for this link.

How I should configure the router to achieve it?

Thanks for your time,

H25E

Comment: Have you tried combining these into a single comment, something like `import(/* webpackPrefetch: false, webpackPreload: false, webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue")` ?

Comment: Yes, and include only /*webpackPrefetch: false*/. Result is always the same. It's a little bit frustating. The only difference is that "about.js" is prefetched as "0.js". So I suppose that comments aren't correctly parsed.

Comment: You may be able to find an answer here - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979

Comment: I have read this post before, but I don't know how to interprete the "/\.map$/" from: ```fileBlacklist: [
          /\.map$/
        ]
```
Do I need a map file?

Comment: This glob pattern simply states which files should not be prefetched. In the given example MAP files won't be prefetched but you can add your own glob pattern.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Post your comment as answer if you want in order to select it as solved. Do we know why the magic comments don't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [discussion on Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979) which offers some tips relevant to your situation.

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('prefetch').tap(options => {
      options.fileBlackList.push([/MyChunkName(.*)\.js$/]);
      return options;
    });
  }
};
```

Vue-CLI by default automatically prefetches all dynamic imports - so you have to add a blacklist.

The magic comments for Webpack (`webpackPrefetch` and probably `webpackPreload` too) accept either `true` or a number (index) - but do not accept `false` argument.